# Javascript wildcard?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wildcard

I have a bit of Javascript that works with a plugin so that a static text link corresponds to a specific slide in a jquery slider. It looks like this:

```
$("a.gibbs").click(function(){
  $('#anyslider').anythingSlider('.gibbs');
  });
});
```

So basically, any link with class .gibbs will move the slider to the li with class .gibbs.

What I'm wondering is, since I have close to 50 slides, is there any way to just say "any link with a class .x will move the slider to the li with the same class .x" - without having to write new javascript for all 50 classes?

Thanks :)

Comment: what plugin are you using? kind of hard to say without knowing what the plugin does

Comment: It's called anything slider, it's a pretty straightforward jquery slider that allows any kind of content. [AnythingSlider](http://css-tricks.com/anythingslider-jquery-plugin/)

Comment: save the class of the clicked item var something = $(this).attr('class'); and insert it in the code

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you, then yes.

Assuming that there's only one class on the element getting the handler,

```
$("a[class]").click(function(){
  $('#anyslider').anythingSlider('li.' + this.className);
});
```

This applies the handler to *any* `a` element that has at least one class. You'll likely want to narrow it a bit, but I don't know how without more information from you.

Also, there may be better solutions, but again, we would need more info.

---

Even if there are multiple classes, you could make it work as long as one of the classes matches the target.

```
$("a[class]").click(function(){
  $('#anyslider').anythingSlider('li.' + this.className.split(/\s+/).join(',li.');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. How would your script know which classes are meant? Of course you can put that in a loop:

```
var $slider = $('#anyslider');
["gibbs", "gobbs", "gabbs", ...].forEach(function(className) {
     $("a."+className).click(function(){
         $slider.anythingSlider('.'+className);
     });
});
```

Or, if you have just a single class on each of the links:

```
$("a.gibbs, a.gobbs, a.gabbs, ...").click(function moveToMyClass() {
     $('#anyslider').anythingSlider('.'+this.className);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the API, it seems like you could do something like

```
$("a.gibbs").click(function(){
  var slide = $('#anyslider ' + this.className));
  $('#anyslider').anythingSlider(slide.index());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have multiple class names for any given element.

so: `<a class='slideme' id='gibbs'>Slideable stuff...</a>`

It depends on what the `anythingSlider()` method expects as a parameter, but if it accepts an ID rather than a class, you could do this:

```
$("a.slideme").click(function(){
  $('#anyslider').anythingSlider('#'.this.id);
});
```

If it accepts an DOM object or a jQuery object, just use `this` or `$(this)` respectively.